# Android Databinding radiogroups

Tags: java, android

Android have a new feature for binding UI views with models objects.

The examples just use textviews...

Someone has an example using radiogroups, checks or more complex view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out this library for databinding lists/recyler-views with adapters https://github.com/evant/binding-collection-adapter.

There is a sample app where they implement binding on the ListViews/RecyclerViews